# DocuSign API: “Invalid Signature Credentials”

Tags: docusignapi

I am using embedded signing as well as remote signing for different users with different recepientIDs. We are using Soap APIs for this application. The application works perfectly using developer account with

- DocuSign webservice(UAT) : https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx

But now we are trying the same codebase with our production account which is at na2 region. We are facing an issue "Invalid Signature Credentials".

- DocuSign webservice(Prod) : https://na2.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx

Please let me know if I am missing anything or something needs to be configured for production account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which API call are you making?  Please post the request that you are sending out...

Comment: @Ergin It throws the error when I am calling "RequestRecipientToken" web method

Comment: As @Ergin suggested, it's very difficult to figure out what is going wrong without actually see what's being requested. (include headers but strip out the contents of Username, Password and IntegratorKey.